# How to draw a rectangle and put a text inside it

Tags: wxpython

I am using wxPython for first time. My requirement is to create a rectangular box and write some text in it. I tried to achieve the same but the rectangular box is not getting rendered in the windows frame:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        self.SetTitle('BPSK')
        self.Maximize(True)
        self.Show(True)
        dc = wx.WindowDC(self)
        dc.DrawRectangle(10, 10, 200, 200)


    def ShowMessage(self, message):
        wx.MessageBox(message, 'Info',
            wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)


def main():
    ex = wx.App()
    Example(None)
    ex.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am not sure what wrong I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your example:

While it does work (at least on wxPython 2.9.5.1/msw), it is probably not what you want:

- The `wx.WindowDC` paints on the whole `wx.Frame` (instead of the interior of the frame). You would use a `wx.ClientDC` to only draw onto the interior (and not the titlebar and the icons of the frame).

However, there will be another problem: As soon as you minimize the frame, the graphics will be gone.

To cut it short, see the following example **for the simplest way to draw properly** in the [wxPython wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/VerySimpleDrawing) (meaning, fire off some drawing commands and having it repainted/refreshed properly).

The other way would be to draw a bitmap yourself (`wx.Bitmap` + `wx.MemoryDC` + `wx.GraphicsContext` for antialiased drawing) and use a `wx.StaticBitmap` to have it displayed.